# How do you specify what file in a directory will load up ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Rudimentary folder structure:

```
<root>
---<admin>
------index.aspx
------[other files]
---index.aspx
```

When I navigate to mywebsite.com/admin/, all I get is a directory listing.  How can I get it to load up `index.aspx` automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to change the default documents list on the IIS website configuration dialog. If you don't have access to this, change index.aspx to default.aspx. The ASP.NET install sets default.aspx in the list, and it's the reason all new VS web projects start with a Default.aspx page.

Comment: good call. i looked at the list, and index.aspx was on there as well. no biggie switching it to default.aspx and it works like a charm (brain fried, end of the day, stupid mistakes) thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming index.aspx to Default.aspx